# Completing the square with simple polys

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am suppose to rewrite $x^2 + x + 1$ by completing the square. I don't really know what that means but I know that if I add 3 at the end of this I get

$$(x + 2) (x - 1) - 3$$ this is the same as the original now but the answer isn't right. What is wrong with what I did? It seems a lot cleaner than the answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In general, $$\color{purple}{(ax+b)^2= a^2x^2+2abx+b^2}.$$

What you have is $x^2 + x + 1$. To complete the square, what you want to do is find $a$, $b$, $c$ in such a way that $x^2 + x + 1 = (ax + b)^2 + c$.

Now,

$$\begin{align}
x^2 + x + 1 & = (ax + b)^2 + c \\
x^2 + x + 1 & = a^2x^2+2abx+b^2 + c \\
\end{align}$$

Now let's color the last equation. We then have $$ \color{red}{x^2} + \color{orange}{x} + \color{blue}{1} = \color{red}{a^2x^2}+\color{orange}{2abx}+\color{blue}{b^2 + c}.$$

Then, for the colored equation above, we equate the coefficients of left hand side to the right hand side of the equation. Then we have three things:
$$\begin{align} \tag 1
\color{red}{x^2} & \equiv \color{red}{a^2x^2} \\  \tag2
\color{orange}x & \equiv \color{orange}{2abx}  \\ \tag3
\color{blue}1 & \equiv \color{blue}{b^2 + c}  \\ 
\end{align}$$

- Solving equation $(1)$, we have 
  $x^2 \equiv a^2x^2 \Rightarrow a^2 = 1 \Rightarrow a= 1$ or $a= -1$,
- Solving equation $(2)$, we have 
  $x \equiv 2abx \Rightarrow 1 = 2ab \Rightarrow b = \dfrac{1}{2a}$. From above, if $a= 1$ then $b= \dfrac{1}{2}$. If $a= -1$ then $b= -\dfrac{1}{2}$.
- Solving equation $(3)$, we have $1 \equiv b^2 + c \Rightarrow c= 1 - b^2$. From above, if $b= \dfrac{1}{2}$ then $c= \dfrac{3}{4}$. If $b= -\dfrac{1}{2}$ then $c= \dfrac{3}{4}$ as well.

In conclusion, we have the set of solutions $\color{navy}{a=1, b= \dfrac{1}{2}, c= \dfrac{3}{4}}$ or $\color{maroon}{a=-1, b= -\dfrac{1}{2}, c= \dfrac{3}{4}}$.

Check the answer, plug the values of $a$, $b$, $c$ into $(ax+b)^2+c$ and expand it. If you get $x^2 + x + 1$, then it is correct.

For $\color{navy}{a=1, b= \dfrac{1}{2}, c= \dfrac{3}{4}}$, we have $$\left(x+\frac{1}{2}\right)^2+ \frac{3}{4}= x^2 + 2(1)\frac{1}{2}x^2 + \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{2} + \frac{3}{4} = x^2 + x + 1.$$

For $\color{maroon}{a=-1, b= -\dfrac{1}{2}, c= \dfrac{3}{4}}$, we have $$\left(-x-\frac{1}{2}\right)^2+ \frac{3}{4}= (-x)^2 + 2(-1)\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)x^2 + \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{2} + \frac{3}{4} = x^2 + x + 1.$$

So the answer to your question is either $$\left(x+\dfrac{1}{2}\right)^2+ \dfrac{3}{4}$$ or $$\left(-x-\frac{1}{2}\right)^2+ \frac{3}{4}.$$

The first one looks prettier. I would go with that. Hope this helps.

---

Some more examples. Let's start with an easy one.

**Example 1**
Suppose someone asks you to complete the square of $$x^2+2x+3. \tag{A1}$$ Now consider $(x+1)^2$. Expanding that, we have $$(x+1)^2 = x^2 + 2x+ 1.  \tag{A2}$$ You want to complete the square of $x^2+2x+3$. Notice that to get $x^2+2x+3$ from equation $(A2)$, all you have to do is add the number $2$ to both sides of equation $(A2)$, since both $(A1)$ and $(A2)$ both have $x^2$ and $2x$. Then 
$$\begin{align}(x+1)^2 +\color{red}2 &= x^2 + 2x+ 1 +\color{red}2 \\
(x+1)^2 +2 & = x^2 + 2x+ 3.
\end{align}$$ And there you have it, the answer is $(x+1)^2 +2$.

**Example 2**
Now, back to your question. You want to complete the square of $$x^2+x+1. \tag{B}$$ Now consider $(x+1)^2$. Expanding that, we have $$(x+1)^2 = x^2 + 2x+ 1. \tag {C}$$ Equation $(B)$ and $(C)$ both have $x^2$, but equation $(B)$ has $x$ in it, while equation $(C)$  has $2x$. We then have to try another expansion. So you consider $\left(x+\frac{1}{2}\right)^2$. We then get $$\left(x+\frac{1}{2}\right)^2= x^2 + x + \frac{1}{4} \tag{D}$$ Aha! They now both have $x$. All you have to do now is add a number to both sides of equation $(D)$ so that the right hand side equals $x^2+x+1$. So you add $\frac{3}{4}$ to both sides of equation $(D)$. Then you have

$$\begin{align}
\left(x+\frac{1}{2}\right)^2 & = x^2 + x + \frac{1}{4} \\
\left(x+\dfrac{1}{2}\right)^2+ \color{red}{\dfrac{3}{4}} & = x^2 + x + \frac{1}{4} + \color{red}{\dfrac{3}{4}} \\
\left(x+\dfrac{1}{2}\right)^2+ {\dfrac{3}{4}} & = x^2 + x + 1.
\end{align}$$

And so the answer is $\left(x+\dfrac{1}{2}\right)^2+ {\dfrac{3}{4}}$.

**Example 3**
Suppose you want to complete the square of $$9x^2+3x+1. \tag{E}$$ You know $(3x)^2=9x^2$, so you consider $(3x+1)^2$. Expanding that, we have $$(3x+1)^2 = 9x^2 + 6x+ 1. \tag {F}$$ Equation $(E)$ and $(F)$ both have $9x^2$, but equation $(E)$ has $3x$ in it, while equation $(F)$  has $6x$. We then have to try another expansion. So you consider $\left(3x+\frac{1}{2}\right)^2$. We then get $$\left(3x+\frac{1}{2}\right)^2= 9x^2 + 3x + \frac{1}{4} \tag{G}$$ They now both have $3x$. All you have to do now is add a number to both sides of equation $(G)$ so that the right hand side equals $9x^2+3x+1$. So you add $\frac{3}{4}$ to both sides of equation $(G)$. Then you have

$$\begin{align}
\left(3x+\frac{1}{2}\right)^2 & = 9x^2 + 3x + \frac{1}{4} \\
\left(3x+\dfrac{1}{2}\right)^2+ \color{red}{\dfrac{3}{4}} & = 9x^2 + 3x + \frac{1}{4} + \color{red}{\dfrac{3}{4}} \\
\left(3x+\dfrac{1}{2}\right)^2+ {\dfrac{3}{4}} & = 9x^2 + 3x + 1.
\end{align}$$

And so the answer is $\left(3x+\dfrac{1}{2}\right)^2+ {\dfrac{3}{4}}$.

With practice, it will get easier.

Comment: Thank you but that seems very intensive and complex, is there not an easier way to do these? I am just trying to briefly study some algebra before I study calculus before i study calculus 2.

Comment: @Jordan I added some examples. Hope it helps.

Comment: This is a nice complete instructive answer.

Answer (score 3):

$$
x^2 + x +1 = x^2 + x + \frac14 + \frac34 = (x+\frac12)^2 + \frac34
$$

Answer (score 2):

When I hear completing the square, I think of a method to solve a quadratic equation such as

$$x^2+x+1=0$$

The idea is to make the left side a square and take the square root of both sides.  So what constant do we add to both sides?  Since

$$(x+a)^2=x^2+2ax+a^2$$

We take half of our $x$ term to find our value for $a$.

$$2a=1,a=\frac12$$
$$(x+\frac12)^2=x^2+x+\frac14$$

So to complete the square, we subtract $\frac34$ from both sides to get

$$x^2+x+\frac14=(x+\frac12)^2=-\frac34$$

In this case, the problem would have no real roots.  My guess is the form your teacher wants is

$$(x+\frac12)^2+\frac34$$

Comment: I missed the part where you knew how to subtract 3/4s.

Comment: @Jordan If $a=\frac12,a^2=\frac14$.  Subtracting $\frac34$ completes the square on the left side of the equation.

Answer (score 1):

Completing the square takes a polynomial that looks like
$$x^2+ax+b$$
and says, what numbers $c$ and $d$ work to make
$$x^2+ax+b=(x-c)^2+d\quad ?$$
Note that
$$\begin{align*}
(x-c)^2+d&=\bigg[(x-c)(x-c)\bigg]+d\\\\\\
&=\bigg[x^2-2cx+c^2\bigg]+d\\\\\\
&=x^2-2cx+c^2+d\\\\\\
&=x^2+(-2c)x+(c^2+d).\\\\\\
\end{align*}$$
Since the polynomials $$x^2+ax+b\qquad\qquad x^2+(-2c)x+(c^2+d)$$ are supposed to be equal, we must have that
$$a=-2c\qquad b=c^2+d,$$
or after rewriting,
$$c=-\frac{a}{2}\qquad d=b-c^2.$$
When $a=1$ and $b=1$, what do you get?

Comment: I lost you at "Note that" that is very confusing and complex, do I need to memorize that or just know that it works?

Comment: @Jordan: You should memorize that
$$(x-c)^2=x^2-2cx+c^2$$
**and** understand why it is true.

Comment: I recognize it as a difference of squares but I don't understand how to transform this problem into it.

Comment: @Jordan: It is not a difference of squares. A difference of squares would be 
$$p^2-q^2$$
for some $p$ and $q$. The expression
$$(x-c)^2$$
is the square of a difference, which is not the same thing. Hopefully you are aware that
$$p^2+q^2\neq (p+q)^2\qquad\text{and}\qquad p^2-q^2\neq (p-q)^2.$$ I also explain the relevance of $(x-c)^2$ to the problem in my answer.

Comment: I am kind of lost as to where to start on this.